# Django and Celery Confusion

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

After reading a lot of blogposts, I decided to switch from crontab to Celery for my middle-scale Django project. I have a few things I didn't understand:

1- I'm planning to start a micro EC2 instance which will be dedicated to RabbitMQ, would this be sufficient for a small-to-medium heavy tasking? (Such as dispatching periodical e-mails to Amazon SES).

2- Computing of tasks, does compution of tasks occur on the Django server or the rabbitMQ server (assuming the rabbitMQ is on a seperate server)?

3- When I need to grow my system and have 2 or more application servers behind a load balancer, do these two celery machines need to connect to the same rabbitMQ vhost? Assuming application servers are the carbon copy and tasks are same and everything is sync on the database level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know the answer to this question, but you can definitely configure it to be suitable (e.g. use `-c1` for a single process worker to avoid using much memory, or eventlet/gevent pools), see also the `--autoscale` option.  The choice of broker transport also matters here, the ones that are not polling are more CPU effective (rabbitmq/redis/beanstalk).
2. Computing happens on the workers, the broker is only responsible for accepting, routing and delivering messages (and persisting messages to disk when necessary).
3. To add additional workers these should indeed connect to the same virtual host. You would
   only use separate virtual hosts if you would want applications to have separate message buses.